# MS Access 2013 - keep entries even on form.close

Tags: ms-access

I was wondering if someone can help me. 
What i would like to do is:

I have 2 textfield `PriceRangeOne` `PriceRangeTwo`
Currently when there's an Entry for PriceRangeOne = 12 and PriceRangeTwo = 25 and the user closes the form or leaves to an other tab the entries are beeing removed.
Does anyone know a way to keep them?

They are just textfields and have no binding to any datasource.

Comment: When the form closes it can't retain any values on the form itself. Perhaps on the Form_Close event you can set some variables contents with the values on the form? Then you can use those someplace else where you need them

Comment: Do you mean something like that?
`If Me.Dirty Then
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name`

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest TempVars?

```
TempVars("myVariable") = "def"
Debug.Print TempVars("myVariable")
```

TempVars are a publicly available collection of global values that you can reference in code, queries, forms and reports, and they persist when the database is re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

(See my answer below for my solution to the OP's question)

This answer is off-topic, but I felt I needed to comment on Ryan's code example. Judging by the OP's lack of success with this code, it is being put in the form's class module. But, this can't work, and here's why:

Forms are objects. As such, they have a lifetime dictated by a reference variable, which in this case is stored in the Forms() collection. When you close the form, it's class instance is terminated, effectively erasing it from memory as far as the VBA interpreter is concerned.

So, what you have done in your code:

```
Public myString1 As String
Public myString2 As String
```

is declare two *class-level* public properties. Variables `myString1` and `myString2` only live as long as the class does (as long as the form is open). Further, they are only directly modifiable by code residing within the form's class.

"But what about the `Public` declaration?", you might ask. "Doesn't that make the variable public to all code in the project?". No, it does not. `Public` in this context is really declaring a public property for the class.

So, this code snippet:

```
Public myString1 As String
```

Is shorthand for:

```
Private thisString1 As String

Public Property Get myString1() As String
     myString1 = thisString1
End Property
Public Property Let myString1(newString As String)
    thisString1 = newString
End Property
```

In object terms, you have defined a read/write property called `myString1`, that allows outside code to modify and retrieve the property value, *as long as there exists an active instance* of the class with a live value for `thisString1`.

So, what is wrong with this example is that the values held by public properties `myString1` and `myString2` in the form class module vanish when the form closes. Some other global mechanism, such as TempVars(), must be used.